# How to functionally compose futures?

Tags: python, future, python-multithreading, functor, concurrent.futures

I have a thread object that I can't distribute across a ProcessPoolExecutor, but would like to return a future. If I already have a future, is there a way to apply to its completed value, eg, `Future a -> (a -> b) -> Future b`?

```
import concurrent.futures
import threading

def three(x):
    return 2+x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    trackedItem = (3, threading.Event())
    pool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(3)
    poolJob = (q.submit(three, trackedItem[0]),trackedItem[1]) #(Future(int), Event)
    *** something magic goes here ***
    #Trying to transform it into Future(int,Event)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way which uses a simpler setup code, without `threading.Event` as that doesn't seem necessary to solve the problem. Basically, you can create `future_b` as a new `Future()` yourself, and use the `add_done_callback` method on `future_a` to set the result of `future_b`. Here, `func_a` is the computation to compute the result of `future_a`, and `func_b` is the computation to compute the result of `future_b` using the result of `future_a`.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, Future

def func_a(x):
    return 2 + x

def func_b(x):
    return 10 * x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(3)
    future_a = pool.submit(func_a, 3)

    future_b = Future()
    future_b.set_running_or_notify_cancel()

    def callback(f):
        x = f.result()
        y = func_b(x)
        future_b.set_result(y)

    future_a.add_done_callback(callback)

    print(future_b.result()) # 50
```

If you want a helper function to do this, you can write one: `map_future` takes a future and a mapping function, and returns the new mapped future as required. This version handles an exception in case `f.result()` or `func_b` throws one:

```py
def map_future(future_a, func):
    future_b = Future()
    future_b.set_running_or_notify_cancel()

    def callback(f):
        try:
            x = f.result()
            y = func(x)
            future_b.set_result(y)
        except Exception as e:
            future_b.set_exception(e)

    future_a.add_done_callback(callback)
    return future_b
```

Caveats: this goes against the advice in the documentation for the `Future` class, which says:

> `Future` instances are created by `Executor.submit()` and should not be created directly except for testing.

Also, if you have any errors which aren't subclasses of `Exception` in the callback, they will be "logged and ignored" according to the docs. I've chosen to only catch `Exception` in this code for simplicity, but you might prefer the `sys.exc_info()[0]` way of catching every possible thing that could be raised.

Answer (score 0):

@kaya3 provided a great answer but I ran into problem when adding exception handling for it to close the pool. You can find my example `cpchung_example` below to see how to compose future functionally. It still remains to add exception-handling to it that I dont have a good solution yet.

For comparison, I put them all into one file:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, Future
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor


def map_future(future_a, func):
    future_b = Future()
    future_b.set_running_or_notify_cancel()

    def callback(f):
        try:
            x = f.result()
            y = func(x)
            future_b.set_result(y)
        except Exception as e:

            future_b.set_exception(e)

    future_a.add_done_callback(callback)
    return future_b


def func_a(x):
    return 2 + x


def func_b(x):
    return 3 * x


def func_c(x):
    raise NameError('Hi There')
    return 4 * x


def kaya3_example():
    future_a = pool.submit(func_a, 3)

    future_b = Future()
    future_b.set_running_or_notify_cancel()

    def callback(f):
        x = f.result()
        y = func_b(x)
        future_b.set_result(y)

    future_a.add_done_callback(callback)

    print(future_b.result())  # 50


def exception_handling():
    try:

        future_a = pool.submit(func_a, 3)
        future_b = map_future(future_a, func_b)
        future_c = map_future(future_b, func_c)

        print(future_c.result())

    except Exception as e:
        pool.shutdown()

    pool.shutdown()


def f(x, y):
    return x * y


def cpchung_example():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        a = executor.submit(f, 2, 3)
        b = executor.submit(f, 4, 5)
        c = executor.submit(f, a.result(), b.result())

        print(c.result())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(3)

    kaya3_example()

    cpchung_example()

    # exception_handling()  # not working, still wip
```

Comment: This is pretty daggone nifty and I can't believe I'm not the only one playing in this space anymore!

Comment: The problem here is that `c = executor.submit` blocks. Imagine you have `c = executor.submit(f, a.result(), b.result()); d = executor.submit(f, a.result(), a.result())`. Here, `d` only depends on `a`, but it will wait until `b` and `c` are finished.

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions don't support cancellation. I suggest:

```
from concurrent.futures import Future
from typing import TypeVar

I = TypeVar("I")
O = TypeVar("O")


class _ComposingFuture(Future):

    def __init__(self, delegate: Future[I], xform: Callback[[I], O]):
        self._delegate = delegate
        self._xform = xform
        super().__init__()
        delegate.add_done_callback(self._callback)

    def cancel(self) -> bool:
        if not self._delegate.cancel():
            return False
        super().cancel()
        return True

    def _callback(self, delegate: Future) -> None:
        if delegate.cancelled():
            super().cancel()
        else:
            try:
                self.set_result(self._xform(delegate.result()))
            except Exception as e:
                self.set_exception(e)


def compose(future: Future[I], xform: Callable[[I], O]) -> Future[O]:
    return _ComposingFuture(future, xform)
```